# How can I use different fonts for different objects in Unity?

Tags: unity

In Unity 3.5, I have a font that is strangely linked to four game objects. I want to put separate fonts on each object.

In the Inspector, when I click on the circle icon next to the "Text" attribute, I can select a font.  But, then it changes the font on the other three objects as well.

I was hoping Unity would have something like a material ID from 3DS Max. If I could put a new material ID on the other objects, hopefully I could assign a new font to the text mesh. Regardless, is there a way to assign a different font to each of my objects?

Comment: Welcome to the site; please read the [help]. On this site we prefer that you only include a single question per post, and certain kinds of questions (such as those where the answer is "yes" or "no") aren't consider appropriate. In particular, the original title of your question represents an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so I've adjusted it to focus on the actual issue you seem to be having (setting up different fonts for different objects).

Comment: Try looking up GUISkins